# USB Camera Timeout/Busy in Long Term Operation

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, v4l2, usb-camera

**TLDR:** USB Camera stops returning images with continued usage.

I am running a continuous application using Raspberry Pi4, Ubuntu, OpenCV where I am capturing an image once every 5 seconds and sending that to an API. I'm having an issue where I am getting `None` frames after some time and the camera becomes unresponsive.

I've tried using V4L2 and fswebcam directly in the command line as tests, but I keep getting the same issue of the camera either being completely unresponsive or taking several minutes to capture an image.

**Simplified Code**

```
import cv2
import time

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)
cam.set(3,1280)
cam.set(4,720)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))

while True:
     time.sleep(5)
     ret , frame = cam.read()
```

This runs fine at first, but the images start coming in slower and slower over time. Eventually, it returns `None` frame and becomes unresponsive. Subsequent attempts to release and select the camera result in camera select timeout errors.

```
VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout
```

Any idea what would cause the camera to start taking longer and longer to capture the images and why the camera becomes unresponsive?

Comment: did you try not convert the video stream on the fly with "VideoWriter_fourcc" ? Just comment that line or increase that 5 seconds sleep. Maybe raspberry can't deal with this amount of computation.

Comment: I'm specifying the MJPG format because I'm trying to access the precompressed stream from the camera. I don't believe the pi should be doing anything computationally intensive. The CPU utilization is like 3%.

Comment: set the fourcc first, then other properties. and make sure no other bandwidth-hungry peripherals are on the same usb controller. -- generally it's wasteful to repeatedly open and close the same device. keep it open, keep reading frames, keep a reference to the latest frame, use when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this implementation to avoid having the videocapture resource tied up while you are waiting for 5 seconds?

```
import cv2
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    time.sleep(2)
    cam.set(3,1280)
    cam.set(4,720)
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
    ret , frame = cam.read()
    cam.release()
```

Comment: I've tried doing something similar on the command line with V4L2 and fswebcam where I set the camera and capture - then sleep. It had the same failure condition of erroring out after it ran for a bit. I can try this though.

Comment: Sounds good. you may not even need to wait a full 5 seconds any longer since the pi take considerably longer to initialize a VideoCapture. The important point is cam.release()

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Do you still have this problem when you use a smaller image size?

Comment: Yep, seems to happen at any resolution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by moving my USB camera over to one of the USB 2.0 ports (the black ones). I only saw the problem when I plugged the camera into the USB 3.0 ports (the blue ones)